# Zend File element and setElementsBelongTo()

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

I'm currently trying to create a form using **Zend_Form**. Inside the form there is a **displayGroup** of **File** element and **Text** element. Since it is a dynamic form, I would like the input field names to be in array form (something like the one below).

```
requestRow[1][fileName]
requestRow[1][fileDesc]
requestRow[2][fileName]
requestRow[2][fileDesc]
```

**setElementsBelongTo()** worked for the text elements but not on the File elements. Is it the correct behavior? Or do I need extra method call or attribute/property for that?

If it is the specification, is there any workaround for that?

I have also tried manually setting the File element name with array format but it also doesn't work.

*I'm using Zend 1.12*

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Saw the following comment about the current limitation File element.

> **Posted by Thomas Weidner (thomas) on 2011-09-19T06:30:50.000+0000**
>
> No, this is a limitation of php's file upload capability. From ZF's
> manual:
>
> {quote} File elements in Subforms
>
> When you use file elements in subforms you must set unique names. For
> example, if you name a file element in subform1 "file", you must give
> any file element in subform2 a different name.
>
> If there are 2 file elements with the same name, the second element is
> not be displayed or submitted.
>
> Additionally, file elements are not rendered within the sub-form. So
> when you add a file element into a subform, then the element will be
> rendered within the main form. {quote}
>
> **Posted by Thomas Weidner (thomas) on 2011-09-29T18:11:15.000+0000**
>
> Closing as wont fix as there is actually no way to solve this
> limitation

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11741